# passing arguments into syntax-quoted macros

Tags: clojure, macros

While hunting a bug in one of our clojure modules, I stumbled upon a syntax-quoted macro to which somebody passed arguments. After some debugging I realised that this doesn't work as intended, as the arguments do not have the values they should have.

The below is a minimal representation of the situation encountered in the actual code. It should illustrate the point pretty well:

```
(def testargs {:arg1 "foo"
               :arg2 "bar"})

(defmacro argtest
  [arg1 arg2]
  `(str ~@(arg1 testargs) " " ~@(arg2 testargs))
```

This works nicely as expected if I call the code like this:

```
(argtest :arg1 :arg2)
=> "foo bar"
```

However, if the two arguments are passed in as variables, it does not work so well:

```
(let [arg1 :arg1 arg2 :arg2]
  (argtest arg1 arg2))
=> " "
```

To get to the bottom of the problem, I changed the macro as follows and ran the tests again:

```
(defmacro argtest2
  [arg1 arg2]
  (str arg1 " " arg2))

(argtest2 :arg1 :arg2)
=> ":arg1 :arg2"

(let [argument1 :arg1 argument2 :arg2]
  (argtest2 argument1 argument2))
=> "argument1 argument2"
```

As you can see, what happens is that the variable *names* are passed as values. How can I avoid this? Should I just try to rewrite the code to avoid a macro, or can I somehow make this work?

An obvious solution would of course be something like this:

```
(defmacro argtest
  [arg1 arg2]
  `(str (~arg1 ~testargs) " " (~arg2 ~testargs)))
```

But since the output of the macro is inserted into another code block before evaluation, this is not possible.

Comment: `~testargs` -> `testargs` should work fine?

Comment: (1) If you can change to macro to a function, do it.  (2) If not, do what cfrick said using `~` instead of `~@`, which seems unneeded from what you've shown.

Comment: @cfrick: Yes, that works with what I posted here, but the generated code gets inserted into a threading macro later on, which starts to wildly throw exceptions...

Comment: @Alan Thompson: Thanks, I chose to go with (1). It seems some people definitely like their macros a bit too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forms are not evaluated before being passed to macros as they are with functions.  Without broader context or knowing what you're trying to do, the simplest solution would be to use a function, as you seem to want the arguments evaluated in all cases, though maybe I'm oversimplifying your problem:

```
(defn argtest [arg1 arg2]
  (str (arg1 testargs) " " (arg2 testargs)))
```

Comment: I would have chosen that approach if I would have written the original code, but the author chose to work with macros to generate code using quoted lists stored in a map, and to insert the generated code into a threading macro... I have tried to untangle the mess for about 6 hours now, and following the suggestions here replaced the whole thing with a simple map of functions in less than one. Thanks a lot everybody!